# Set height of an element on multiples of a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way via jquery or javascript to make an element stretch its height to a certain set of numbers? I mean, as it accommodates more content, its height would only follow a pattern of numbers (multiples of a number).

Let's say in multiples of 100... a div's height as it extends taller would only be in this series -- 200px, 300px, 400px, etc. Hence, if it exceeds by just even 1 pixel off 200, it would automatically resize to 300.

It's hard to explain.

I need this because I made a vertically seamless pattern with torn edges and it would totally look perfect if it shows each tile completely.

I only know basic jquery and I don't have a bit of an idea on how to work this out.

My sincerest gratitude to whoever tends to my query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var h = $('div').height();
$('div').height( Math.ceil(h/100) * 100 );
```

Comment: Better: `$('div').height(function(i, h) { return Math.ceil(h / 100) * 100; });`

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$('element').css({ height : (0|(targetHeight + 99) / 100) * 100 });
```

if you want it automatic:

```
$(function(){
    var $elem = $('#element')
    $elem.css({ height : (0|($(elem).height() + 99) / 100) * 100 });
});
```

Comment: @cwolves What does `0|targetHeight` do?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - `Math.floor((targetHeight + 99) / 100)`

Comment: @cwolves `0|x` is equal to `Math.floor(x)`?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - yes, for all numbers < 2^31.  `|` is a bitwise operator, all bitwise ops in JS have an implicit cast-to-int

Comment: `(5 | 9) === 13 // true` Pretty interesting stuff.

Comment: @Robert - bitwise math :)  `(5).toString(2) == "101"` `(9).toString(2) == "1001"` `"101" | "1001" == "1101"` `parseInt("1101", 2) == 13`.  It's actually much faster than other ways of doing the same thing.  `0|` is effectively a "noop", FYI

Answer (score 0):

This function will take the current height and the unit number you want it to snap to, rounding to the nearest multipleOf.

```
function snapHeight(height, multipleOf) {
    return multipleOf * Math.round(height / multipleOf);
}
```

Examples:

```
snapHeight(930, 100); // returns 900
snapHeight(930, 50); // returns 950
$('#element').height(snapHeight($('#element').height(), 100)); // in jQuery
```